# Минимальное разрешение экрана

Tags: вёрстка

Привет! Сейчас, вот именно сейчас, на какую ширину сайта ориентироваться? Год назад ответ однозначно был 960 - 1000, а сейчас?

Comment: 240x320 самое оно) тока это ширина экрана, окошко браузера - меньше)

Comment: хорошо, ужмусь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну лично я всегда делаю ширину 1024px. Почему - потому что смотреть удобно с разных мониторов. 
А для мобильников, если сайт нужен и популярен, надо делать отдельную версию. Но это в идеальном варианте.

Comment: В идеальном варианте - это один сайт с адаптивной версткой, а не делать 33 сайта под разные устройства.

Comment: @Deonis, почему же все крупные сайты отдельно делают мобильную версию?

Comment: @dzhioev, потому, что именно крупные сайты, имеют очень сложную структуру, которую не так уж легко сделать универсальной, адаптировать под различные устройства. Но это лишь исключение, которое подтверждает правило.

Comment: Крупные сайты могут себе позволить и мобильную и планшетную и tv и прочие версии. У них есть ресурсы: временные, денежные, персонал. По теме нужно уж тогда не 1024, а чуть меньше с учетом вертикального скролла из-за которого может появиться горизонтальный :)

Comment: Соглашусь с @Cypher: не 1024, а 1000. Вертикальный скролл никто не отменял.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно париться. На сегодня октябрь 2016, минимум десктопа - это 1280.
Для мобильных 360 минимум, в идеале нужно еще поддерживать 320.
Смотря, что за сайт будет. Если это сайт пенсионного фонда, то можно даже не смотреть мобильную версию. ;)
А самое главное смотрите устройства которые поддерживаются. Кстати яблфон 4/s можно исключить.

Comment: А еще часть пользователей может сидеть на 1280*1024 с крупными шрифтами (например 150%), и останется только 853пикс, например.